# dynamically changing the values of database system variables set in an option file

Tags: mysql, set, configuration-files, system-variable

In MySQL SET syntax page it says following: "To make a global system variable setting permanent, you should set it in an option file". Does this mean that I will not be able to dynamically change the values of variables set in the option file? (I want to change them iteratively via some script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it simply means you are setting a global default value that will survive restarts of the service. The [SET command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html) will still override any defaults in the scope specified (global, session, etc.).

If you are using `SET GLOBAL`s, you have probably already overridden option file defaults.